# Moving an Object on A Grid in Javascript

Tags: javascript, grid

Working through developing a game that uses a function to move a game piece along a 10x10 grid. The player inputs left or right as a string and this will move the piece in the correct direction. I understand how to make this as two seperate functions as moveLeft()/moveRight() but was hoping to get a little bit drier of a solution with a single function that takes left and right as its parameter.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.